# Статическая инициализация указателя на вложенную структуру

Tags: c, gcc, struct

Можно ли и как правильно статически инициализировать указатель на структуру

```
struct ls
{
char *s;
int l;
};

struct test
{
char    *name;
struct  ls  *a, *b;
} test[] =
    {
        {"name", NULL},     
        {"name", NULL, {"test",4} },   //1
        {"name", .b={"test",4}},       //2
        {NULL},
    };
```

Строки 1,2 - ругаются.
Нужны именно указатели  ls  *a, *b, а не struct ls  a, b (с этим всё).
По аналогии char *s[] = {"a","b"}; ??
В описании : [GCC: 6.27 Designated Initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) не нашёл

Comment: кратко - сделать без объявления предварительного имени struct 'b'  как ниже:  
struct ls b;  
struct test test[] = {{"name", .b=&b}};

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали, надо вот так:

```
struct test
  {
   char *name;
   struct ls *a, *b;
  } test[] =
{
   {"name", .a = &(struct ls){"test", 4} }
};
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal